# Dynamic routing in nextjs 13

Tags: next.js, next.js13, next-router, nextjs-dynamic-routing

I want to develop a route which catches multiple parameters in a single route in nextjs 13 for SEO.

One of the sample route is:

```
/how-to-decide-which-{profession}-to-choose-after-{degree}
```

I have checked the documentation of nextjs 13 and did not find anything. Is it possible to create such routes?

Comment: Check out the [official documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing) and the different route types described within. Please note that Stack Overflow requires you to [do your own research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/8003058) before posting a question.

Comment: @FabioNettis I have done my research and did not found anything useful in the documentation

Comment: What you have there looks like a slug. You can use [optional catch all segments](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/dynamic-routes#optional-catch-all-segments) or [normal catch all segements](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/dynamic-routes#catch-all-segments). Can all be found in the documentation, so I strongly doubt that.

Answer (score 1):

Nextjs separates slug segments by slash '/'. No way to automatically separate url segments by '-' or any other character.

Otherwise, if you decide to use '/' for separating your slug segments, I know 2 approaches:

1. **Catch-all** path: `app/posts/[...slug]/page.jsx` catches the following sample url: `/posts/how-to/decide-which/profession/to-choose-after/college`. The `params.slug` parameter here will be: `['how-to','decide-which','profession','to-choose-after','college']`
2. **Parse** your post title by yourself. I would create a normal 'parameter' path with the following directory structure: `app/posts/[post_slug]/page.jsx`. With your example url, `/posts/how-to-decide-which-profession-to-choose-after-degree`, you will get `params.post_slug` as `how-to-decide-which-profession-to-choose-after-degree`. Then split the slug:

   ```
   let splittedSlug = params.post_slug.split('-');
   ```

   Then process it just as you want to.

You may want to [check the docs here](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/dynamic-routes#catch-all-segments). This is all we can do. No way to automatically separate slug segments by any other character but slash '/'